# Quick consecutive notify_all()s won't unlock condition_variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, locking, mutex, condition-variable

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;  // This mutex is used for three purposes:
                  // 1) to synchronize accesses to i
                  // 2) to synchronize accesses to std::cout
                  // 3) for the condition variable cv
int i = 0;

void waits()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
  std::cout << "Waiting... \n";
  cv.wait(lk, [] { return i == 1; });
  std::cout << "..waiting... \n";
  cv.wait(lk);
  std::cout << "...finished waiting. i == 1\n";
}

void signals()
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
      std::cout << "Notifying...\n";
    }
  }
  i = 1;

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  std::cout << "Notifying again...\n";
  cv.notify_all();
  std::cout << "Notifying again2...\n";
  // HERE!
  //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  cv.notify_all();
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t1(waits), t2(waits), t3(waits), t4(signals);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  t4.join();
}
```

When I uncomment the `sleep_for()` line the `condition_variable` will get the notification, program will unblock and exit.

While this is commented it is blocked.

Why is that happening?

Output from uncommented version:

```
Waiting... 
Waiting... 
Waiting... 
Notifying...
Notifying...
Notifying...
Notifying again...
Notifying again2...
..waiting... 
..waiting... 
..waiting... 
...finished waiting. i == 1
...finished waiting. i == 1
...finished waiting. i == 1
```

Comment: What is the point of the second `wait` / `notify` supposed to be?

Comment: @AlanStokes Just proof of concept to try it out.

Comment: If you wait for something that has already happened, you will be waiting a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short form is that the two notifies are occurring before any of the threads wake up.

Once the condition variable has been notified, all of the threads are waking up (or at least the condition variable no longer considers them 'waiting').  A subsequent notify that occurs prior to their next call to `wait()` will simply do nothing.

By introducing a sleep, you give the threads enough time to execute `wait()` a second time, prior to notifying them again, producing the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 4):

Notifications do not queue.  Only things currently waiting get them, and things waiting can spuriously wake up while waiting.

Condition variables are not semaphores: barring doing more reasoning about concurrency than is healthy, they should always be waited with a test, the test value modified and read within the mutex, and the modification to the test value with lock done before the notification, and the notification should occur merely to examine the guarded value (where all information is extracted).

You violated these rules, and your code did not do what you thought it would.  To me, it would be surprising if your code worked.

Value, conditon variable, mutex: three parts, one message.